# CSS :last-of-type selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wanted to use the `:last-of-type` selector to select the last button element in a page menu that I was creating. But it is not working as expected and I can not find out why :/

HTML:

```
<div id="MediaHTML">
    <div id="MediaInnholdFortegnelse">
        <h1>MEDIA KATEGORIER</h1>
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Bilder">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Bilder</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Bilder-Content", class="MIF-Content">
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Lydfiler">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Lydfiler</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Lydfiler-Content", class="MIF-Content">
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Videoer">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Videoer</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Videoer-Content", class="MIF-Content">
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Skjema">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Skjema</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Skjema-Content", class="MIF-Content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS I want to use:

```
#MediaInnholdFortegnelse > button:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0.46vw;
}
```

I was expecting it to select the last button element, but it selects the first one. 
I am quite new to HTML/CSS so it might be obvious, but it would be nice with some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not closing these divs

`<div id="MIF-Bilder-Content", class="MIF-Content">`

`<div id="MIF-Lydfiler-Content", class="MIF-Content">`

`<div id="MIF-Videoer-Content", class="MIF-Content">`

since you are not closing the div the button are treated as children of these div and hence it is no longer immediate children of `MediaInnholdFortegnelse` and so first button will always be the last child which is immediate child of the `MediaInnholdFortegnelse`

**Modified code**

```css
#MediaInnholdFortegnelse > button:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0.46vw;
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="MediaHTML">
    <div id="MediaInnholdFortegnelse">
        <h1>MEDIA KATEGORIER</h1>
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Bilder">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Bilder</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Bilder-Content", class="MIF-Content"></div>
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Lydfiler">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Lydfiler</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Lydfiler-Content", class="MIF-Content"></div>
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Videoer">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Videoer</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Videoer-Content", class="MIF-Content"></div>
        <button type="button", id="MIF-Skjema">
            <div class="MIF-ButtonContent">
                <i class="material-icons md-c">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <p>Skjema</p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div id="MIF-Skjema-Content", class="MIF-Content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, that's an embarrassingly simple mistake, thanks for the help :)

Comment: well that happens sometime with html ;you dont get errors such kind of errors.

Comment: It's marked now, but there was a cooldown of sorts so i had to wait :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If each button have a parent div, you need to use `div:last-of-type button`

```
#MediaInnholdFortegnelse > .MIF-Content:last-of-type button {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

I've made an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/d3xj03tq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using ">" Sign in your CSS. It catches only the immediate children. And the first button is the only immediate children here. And also check your div tags. Maybe you did not finish your div tags in your code